# Disable autorotation for all but one view for iOS5+

Tags: objective-c

just a little confused on how to disable autorotation in all views except one. 
I am using `FGallery` and i only want to enable rotation on that view.

Can anyone tell me how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS 5.x you can implement this method from `UIViewController`, only returning `YES` for your supported orientation:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

For example, to only support portrait:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)) {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Note that this method is deprecated after iOS 6.

Comment: Yes it will. You're only encouraged to stop using it if you only support iOS 6+

Comment: I've put this in ViewController class:

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return NO;
}

Comment: you have to return yes to at least one orientation.. if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) { return YES;} return NO;

Comment: Getting use of undeclared idenetifier 'orientation'. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can't i just return YES to support all rotations on this view? Do i have to make sure that the buttons in the target part of project are selected to, like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6VpY5.png

Comment: If you return YES for everything it will rotate, wasn't that what you wanted to avoid?

Comment: I want to disable rotation apart from one view, but i could disable it in the target in xcode, and just override this in the view controller enabling all rotations, right?

Answer (score 0):

have you implemented the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation method in your view controller?

if you return no to everything except the orientation you want that should get you the desired result.

Comment: Would this overall the settings in the Targets, the 'Supported Interface Orientations'? Thanks.

Comment: returning no in the uiview controller would override a global allow.